# Twitch Embedded Player on Ionic iOS not working

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, twitch, twitch-api

I create a App with Ionic which embed the twitch player for streams and clips.

```
var url = https://player.twitch.tv/?video=v${videoId}&time=${time}&parent=localhost

<iframe [src]='url' frameborder='0' allow='autoplay; encrypted-media' allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

On Android its working perfect but in the iOS App the iframe will not be shown and no player is available. Just a white screen.

Does anybody know what the problem can be related to ios?

Comment: I would suspect it's something with security permissions related to iOS. Either not supported or the manifest file needs some special entry

Comment: Also you should probably pass the url thru angular sanitizer

Comment: I already bypass the url within the code, sorry I dont mentioned that: this.trustedVideoUrl = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.twitchService.getEmbedLiveStreamUrl(this.selectedChannel.channelName));

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. Security limitations are the culprit indeed: I opened the Safari console while the iframe was trying to load and saw this error:

> Refused to load `https://player.twitch.tv/?channel=...&controls=false&parent=localhost&muted=true` because it does not appear in the frame-ancestors directive of the Content Security Policy.

Looking at this security header that Twitch returns, it looks like this:

```
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors http://localhost:* https://localhost:*
```

However, when using the Ionic WebView, according to its [documentation](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview#iosscheme):

> **iosScheme**
>
> `<preference name="iosScheme" value="httpsionic" />`
> Default value is ionic
>
> Configures the Scheme the app uses to load the content.
>
> Values like `http`, `https` or `file` are not valid and will use default value instead.

So your `WKWebView` will have `ionic://locahost` as its application URL by default, which doesn't match the `http://localhost` and `https://localhost` prefixes specified by Twitch.

I tried using `&parent=ionic://localhost` in the Twitch iframe URL. The `WKWebView` doesn't refuse to open the iframe, but Twitch itself freaks out about the special characters in that parameter and refuses to render its player page.

[image: twitch embed error]

To me it seems that currently, iOS Ionic/Cordova Apps and Twitch iframes are mutually exclusive.

**Edit:**
I found a bunch of discussions in the Twitch forum talking about this subject ([1](https://discuss.dev.twitch.tv/t/embedded-player-within-ios-webbased-mobile-app-e-g-ionic-not-working/32268), [2](https://discuss.dev.twitch.tv/t/twitch-embedded-player-updates-in-2020/23956/1)), but none of them went technically in-depth to the point where a working solution or workaround could be found. Unfortunately, threads are closed after 1 month of inactivity, so I had to open yet another [thread](https://discuss.dev.twitch.tv/t/embedded-player-within-ios-web-based-mobile-app-e-g-ionic-not-working/36227) in the Twitch forum explaining the technical details from my point of view. I also added a feature request in their user-voice feedback portal. I'm afraid trying to make Twitch realise / accept that they should do something about mobile embeds is all we can do at this point. Here's the link to it:

https://twitch.uservoice.com/forums/310213-developers/suggestions/44682766-make-embeds-work-on-ios-web-based-apps-like-ionic